# Change an excel path to include a cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a workbook that contains 50,960 paths to other workbooks

I would like to be able to change part of the paths name to the value of a cell in my workbook (the value being a date)

Example:

='Z:\Folder\Data[Workbook 1.xlsm]10-01-18'!V5*

I want to change the part of the path containing this date **10-01-18** to the value of cell **B2** instead (B2 already contains this date in my workbook).

Comment: What is the range of these cells? `A1:A50960`?

Comment: The external spreadsheet has to be opened for `INDIRECT` to work.  You will need to try `Google INDIRECT.EXT` or Harlan Grove's `PULL` function.

Comment: Are you looking for a dynamic solution? This could be achieved with a simple macro. Or even just using Find/Replace on the range with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This is what INDIRECT is for:

```
=INDIRECT("'Z:\Folder\Data[Workbook 1.xlsm]" & TEXT(B2,"mm-dd-yy") & "'!V5")
```

You may need to change the `mm-dd-yy` to `dd-mm-yy` depending on your local settings.

Comment: I keep getting a cell ref error
=INDIRECT("'Z:\Controll Room\Trip Sheets\Trip Sheet 2018\[Trip Sheet 01 January 2018.xlsm]" & TEXT(B2,"dd-mm-yy") & "'!V5")

Thats the actual path

Comment: That wont work for me - is there any work around for this?

Comment: Not with INDIRECT() sorry.